# Still confused about JavaScript Expressions and Statements

Tags: javascript

I found this PDF [here](http://www.fbeedle.com/javascript/69-4ch04.pdf) and in it the author describes an expression as any valid set of literals, variables, operators, function calls and expressions that evaluate to a single value i.e.

```
3 + 7
3 + 7 + 10 + ""
"Dr." + " " + "Pepper"
```

That all seems fine to me. An a statement is any set of declarations, method and function calls and expressions that performs some action i.e.

```
var num = 1
document.write("hello")
```

But later on they refer to the last line of the examples below as statements

```
var salutation = "Greetings, "
var recipient = "Earthlings"
salutation + recipient //statement

var greeting = "Greetings, "
greeting += "Earthlings" //statement
```

Why isn't `salutation + recipient` and `greeting += "Earthlings"` considered an expression when they are adding two strings like in their expression example `"Dr." + " " + "Pepper"`

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a statement can contain expressions.

> **A statement is any set of** declarations, method and function
>   calls and **expressions** that
>   performs some action

Comment: @ Justin - Thanks for the response. I understand that a statement can contain expressions by why is salutation + recipient a statement and "Dr." + "Pepper" an expression? They are both adding strings together.

Comment: @Nick Lowman: An Expression IS a Statement.  An Expression is one kind of Statement.  They aren't *exclusive* categories.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first is a mistake, I suspect the author mean to type `+=` instead of just `+`.  The second is a statement because it's shorthand for

`greeting = greeting + "Earthlings"`

and you are assigning the result of the string concatenation (an expression) back to the original variable (which makes it a statement).